# Continuously loop through a dataset given number of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a certain dataset, which looks like this:

`3          # Number of test cases
3          # Test case 1 has 3 names
ALFRED
SINGH
JOHN
6          # Test case 2 has 6 names
ALPHA
NITRO
ROB
RICHARD
ANON
POPE
1          # Test case 3 has 1 name
FELIX`

So i have stringified this dataset, and my problem is looping through the entire dataset based on number of testcases, and I also have to consider number of names in each test case. i am using javascript for this and this is my current code. it can only do the first test case:

```js
var example = '3\n3\nALFRED\nSINGH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX'

run(example)

function run(input) {
    var lines = input.split('\n')
    var testCases = lines[0]
    lines.shift()
    var n = lines[0]
    lines.shift()
    for (var i =0; i < n; i += 1) {
        var names = lines[i]
        console.log(names)
    }
}
```

My problem is looping through the entire dataset while respecting number of test cases and names.

**Answers**
Multiple correct answers. Going with JaromandaX for identifying the problem 1st.

**ADDITIONAL PROBLEM**

So the answers seem to return a list of all names without considering the test cases. The aim is to group the names in respect to their test cases. so a structure like this (theoretically):

```
{
    "1": ["ALFRED", "SINGH", "JOHN"],
    "2": [...],
    "3": ["FELIX"]
}
```

Comment: you'll need an outer loop for the number of test cases and an inner loop much like you have for the number of names

Comment: @JaromandaX Something like the answer posted below? It doesn't return the intended result. Just returns Test case 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer loop for the test cases - inner loop needs a slight change too

```js
var example = '3\n3\nALFRED\nSINGH\nJOHN\n6\nALPHA\nNITRO\nROB\nRICHARD\nANON\nPOPE\n1\nFELIX';

function run(input) {
    var lines = input.split('\n')
    var testCases = lines.shift();
    var obj = {};
    for (var x = 0; x < testCases; x++) {
        var testCase = obj[x+1] = [];
        var numberOfNames = lines.shift();
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNames; i += 1) {
            testCase.push(lines.shift());
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
console.log(run(example));
```

note, using `lines.shift()` to "read" the values from lines, because shift returns the line that was shifted

Comment: Any idea how I would link the respective names to their test cases? i want to create an array and push the specific names to their respective arrays. this seems to consider all names as equal!

Comment: I can't tell what data structure you would want. Perhaps add it to the question

Comment: There you go - hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

JSFiffler for quick reference : **https://jsfiddle.net/rj1405/vttejren/1/**

You need to loop through the test cases and have to remove the elements using **`shift()`**.

```js
var example = `3
3
ALFRED
SINGH
JOHN
6
ALPHA
NITRO
ROB
RICHARD
ANON
POPE
1
FELIX`;

run(example)

function run(input) {
    var lines = input.split('\n')
    var testCases = lines.shift();
    for(var x = 0; x < testCases; x++){
      var numberOfNames = lines.shift();
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNames; i++) {
          var names = lines.shift();
          console.log(names);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all of test cases. This is the code:

```js
var example = // 'the dataset above (stringified)'

run(example)

function run(input) {
    var lines = input.split('\n')
    var testCases = lines[0]
    lines.shift()
    for(var x = 0; x < testCases; x++){
    
      var numberOfNames = lines[0]
      lines.shift()
      for (var i =0; i < numberOfNames; i += 1) {
          var names = lines.shift()
  
          console.log(names)
      }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
You have to remove those names from array :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, only returns the 1st case. im testing with node.js

Comment: Wait a minute i will debug

Comment: yeah, that wont work - instead of `names = lines[i];` use `name = lines.shift();` ... in fact `var testCases = lines.shift();` as well (no need for two lines of code when 1 works)

Comment: that will break too ... you're still reading `lines[i]` in the loop, but the array is shrinking!! it would be `lines[0]` all the time - except that you can get the name and shift it out of lines using a single line - `name = lines.shift()`